# Scatter Gather Mule Exception : getPayloadAsString(), use getPayloadAsString(DataType.STRING_DATA_TYPE)

Tags: mule, scatter, payload

I am using a Scatter Gather (component mule esb) witch contains many Saleforce Calls , after the Scatter Gather procces i got the following excpetion :

`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException : getPayloadAsString(), use getPayloadAsString(DataType.STRING_DATA_TYPE)`

The config of the Scatter Gather component is by default

There is my xml config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" 
xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"

xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">

<flow name="Test1">

<http:listener config-ref="httpListenerConfig" path="/test1" doc:name="HTTP" 
allowedMethods="POST"/>

<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">

<dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0

%output application/java

—

payload]]></dw:set-payload>

</dw:transform-message>

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Before Scatter Gather"/>

<scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">

<processor-chain>

<sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" query="Query 
code....."/>

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Call Saleforce Number 1"/>

</processor-chain>

<processor-chain>

<sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" query="Query 
code....."/>

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Call Saleforce Number 2"/>

</processor-chain>

...
...

</scatter-gather>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="After Scatter Gather"/>

<foreach doc:name="For Each">

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="First ForEach"/>

<foreach doc:name="For Each">

<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="Second ForEach"/>

<flow-ref name="flowRefTest1" doc:name="flowRefTest1"/>

</foreach>

</foreach>

</flow>

</mule>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this problem guys ?

Comment: Paste your XML config

Comment: @vijaydhanakodi,done

Answer (score 0):

the reason for that sort of output is because the http endpoint in the beginning is not getting proper response to display so try setting payload in a proper format stating the completion after all the calls to Salesforce are done.
Hope this helps